# {$key} or $key?

Tags: php

I came across this function in a wordpress theme.

```
function get( $key ) {
        if ( method_exists( $this, 'get_' . $key ) ) {
            return call_user_func_array( array( $this, 'get_' . $key ), array() );
        } elseif ( property_exists( $this, $key ) ) {
            return $this->{$key};
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Why is {} around $key needed in $this->{$key}? How is $this->$key not ok?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we perpend $ in any variable then it become Variable variable (Variable vars) like $$name

Check this reference for Variable variable.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Here `$this->$key` will become Variable var because it is about public/private/protected variable of class.

So {} in `$this->{$key}` will set $key vars variable of class